Determining when to switch to a numerically stable asymptotic algorithm
I am trying to evaluate the probability density function for the Variance-gamma distribution which is
$$f(x) \propto |x|^{\lambda - \frac{1}{2}}K_{\lambda - \frac{1}{2}}\left(\alpha|x|\right)e^{\beta|x|},$$
where $K_n(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, though this is not an important detail.
This is numerically unstable at both $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$.
For simplicity, let's just focus on the case $x \to \infty$. In this setting, $f(x)$ asymptotically behaves like
$$
C e^{(\beta - \alpha) x}x^{\lambda - 1},
$$
for some constant $C$.
My current approach is to pick some arbitrary large value of $x$, say 100, and switch to the asymptotic expression at that point.
This appears to work fine but I would feel more comfortable if I had a rigorous procedure I could follow to determine an appropriate cut-off point.
I attempted to search for literature on this topic but was not able to find anything, perhaps due to not knowing the correct search terms.
A direct response or link to a suitable reference would be appreciated.
